# Jenkins eMail configuration for outlook in macOS

Tags: jenkins, java-8, outlook, smtp, macos-high-sierra

Environment details

- Jenkins version 2.107.1
- java version "1.8.0_161"
- macOS High Sierra 10.13.3 (17D47)
- Mailer Plugin 1.21

Following are the setting that I've applied inside Manage Jenkins -> Configure System

### Jenkins Locataion

System Admin e-mail address = myname@companyname.com

### E-mail Notification

- SMTP server = smtp.office365.com
- Default user e-mail suffix = (kept
  empty)
- Use SMTP Authentication = checked (enabled)
- User Name =    myname@companyname.com
- Password = *****
- Use SSL = (kept unchecked)
- SMTP Port = 587
- Reply-To Address = myname@companyname.com
- Charset =    UTF-8

When I try to test email using "Test configuration" button on the same page, I'm getting following error.

> javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 5.5.4 Invalid domain name
>   [HK2PR02CA0178.apcprd02.prod.outlook.com] ...

What's the wrong configuration that I've given?

In addition I've added following line in my jenkins-runner.sh, which is inside /Library/Application Support/Jenkins

```
javaArgs="$javaArgs -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true" # Starts TLS for Office365 SMTP Authentication
```

Comment: did you try `Use SSL` to `checked`? because you are passing java arg. so remove java arg and enable the checkbox. Did you get the same result?

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy yes, I've tried out that and it will provide `javax.net.ssl.SSLException` message